# What is a Production Compiler?

Tags: c, compilation

"Production compilers also exist for several other machines, including the IBM System/370, the Honeywell 6000, and the Interdata 8/32."

Comment: Where did you find this text, and in what context?

Comment: Without more context we can offer only guesses, such as that "production" is meant as an alternative to "experimental" or similar.

Comment: It's a quote from the K&R book.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits ayyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers which are production-ready. Ie. It conforms to all requirements to be used in a production environment. It generates stable, executable software for the platform it is designed to.

This is as opposed to an experimental compiler or an in-development compiler.